# ColdFusion 10 CFCHART, how to pass dynamic variables via JavaScript API method?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfchart

I am using the [cfchart](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfchart) tag in ColdFusion 10 (zingcharts). The page containing the chart is receiving data via websocket and I am trying to pass some of this data to the chart at regular intervals with JavaScript, using:

```
var x = data.number;
var handle = ColdFusion.Chart.getChartHandle();
handle.exec('mychart', 'appendseriesvalues', '{"plotindex": 0, "values": [x]}');
```

The above code works fine if I enter an actual number instead of `x`, for example 
`"values": [1.1]` works fine. However if I try and pass in a number by way of a dynamic variable, it does not work and throws this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how to accomplish this?

Comment: I would suggest not using `cfchart` in ColdFusion 10. I have played around quite a bit with this functionality, and I find it is actually easier to use ZingCharts directly, rather than use the implementation in ColdFusion 10 - especially when it comes to formatting and styling the charts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a JSON string to handle.exec, which is turned into a JS object in a different place to where your x variable is defined, and thus causing the error.

Instead, let x be resolved as part of the string and it should work:

```
handle.exec( ... , '{"plotindex": 0, "values": ['+x+']}');
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much for that Peter !! I was pulling my hair out...very much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. It _might_ be possible to pass in an object directly (not a string), then you could do `handle.exec( ... , {"plotindex": 0, "values": [x]} )` but I don't know if cfchart works like that or not.

Answer (score 4):

Following on from @PeterBoughton's answer/comment, the [ZingCharts API is *really* well documented](http://www.zingchart.com/reference/api-methods.html). So, yes, you can pass an object rather than a JSON representation of one (based on the code example on that page). That would be a preferable approach.

Having messed around with `<cfchart>` and ZingCharts directly... I find it's much easier to do the latter, and remove `<cfchart>` from the equation altogether. There's little gain in becoming an expert in `<cfchart>` (it's not a marketable skill), whereas being comfortable using Javascript libraries directly (if not specifically ZingCharts) is a better tool to have in one's belt.